# Kick out/Force log out users from browser session

Tags: node.js, session

I have a NodeJS project where users sign up, and their fingerprint will be stored in the MongoDB database. And if the signed up users log in with a different device they used to sign up, then they will receive an email saying that there is an unrecognized device signing in, and they can check the related activities.

Once they go to the dashboard and check the activities, they can choose to keep the users or kick them out/ force logout them from the session.

My questions is, how can I make the admin user kick other users out from the session? Is it through deleting their session cookies? What are the other methods I can use to implement in the backend site?